# aligning space between two buttons and placeholder query

Tags: html, css, button, placeholder

i have two doubts. First one is added two buttons on top. how can i align the space between two buttons? secondly i added a text box and given placeholder as search. but in output browser is showing the last letter 'h'.I added an output image below. I am a beginner in html and css. Sincere help will be appreciated.
[![

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
   
}

header{

    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;  
    margin-left: 180px;

    
}

.menu ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
  }

.btn{
    margin-right: 250px;
    
    
}
  .btn1 {
    background-color: #4C5FD5;
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: none;
    
    
  }

  .btn1:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .herosec{
    
    text-align: center;
    
    
  }

  .content{
    background-color: #dadbf1;
    height: 400px;
    
    
    
  }

  .content h1{

    padding-top: 80px;
    font-size: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;

    
  }

  .content input{

    width: 450px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Abstract</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn">
            <button class="btn1">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn1">Signin</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <hero class="herosec">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>How can we help?</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search">
        </div>
    </hero>
    
</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XlKc.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XlKc.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here an example about what you want. You can use flex positions.

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
   
}

header{
    background-color: black;   
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #fff; 
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 50px;  
    
}

.menu ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    display:flex;
  }

.btn{
    // margin-right: 250px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
  .btn1 {
    background-color: #4C5FD5;
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-left : 16px;
    margin-right : 16px;
  }

  .btn1:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .herosec{
    
    text-align: center;
    
    
  }

  .content{
    background-color: #dadbf1;
    height: 400px;
    
    
    
  }

  .content h1{

    padding-top: 80px;
    font-size: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;

    
  }

  .content input{

    width: 450px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Abstract</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn">
                 <button class="btn1">Submit</button>
                 <button class="btn1">Signin</button>
            </div>
       </div>
    </header>
    <hero class="herosec">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>How can we help?</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search">
        </div>
    </hero>
    
</body>
</html>
```